# How to use cogroup for join

Tags: join, apache-pig

I have this join.

```
A = Join smallTableBigEnoughForInMemory on (F1,F2) RIGHT OUTER, massive on (F1,F2);

B = Join anotherSmallTableBigforInMemory on (F1,F3 ) RIGHT OUTER, massive on (F1,F3);
```

Since both joins are using one common key, I was wondering if COGROUP can be used for joining data efficiently. Please note this is a RIGHT outer join.

I did think about cogrouping on F1, but small tables has multiple combination ( 200-300) on single key so I have not used join using single key.

I think partitioning may help but data has skew and I am not sure how to use it in Pig

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Pig's implementation of fragment-replicate joins. See the O'Reilly book [Programming Pig](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/) for more details about the different join implementations. (See in particular Chapter 8, *Making Pig Fly*.)

In a fragment-replicate join, no reduce phase is required because each record of the large input is streamed through the mapper, matched up with any records of the small input (which is entirely in memory), and output.  However, you must be careful not to do this kind of join with an input which will not fit into memory -- Pig will issue an error and the job will fail.

In Pig's implementation, the large input must be given first, so you will actually be doing a left outer join.  Just tack on "using 'replicated'":

```
A = JOIN massive BY (F1,F2) LEFT OUTER, smallTableBigEnoughForInMemory BY (F1,F2) USING 'replicated';
```

The join for B will be similar.